# Java RMI example that's not for localhost

Tags: java, rmi

I'm trying to write a program for Client/Server communication using RMI and this subject is new to me.  I've looked at ton of examples to see if I can try to understand it and they all seem to be designed using local host.  My program won't be run on localhost, it will be connecting to Server which is a whole different machine.

If anyone can show me just a simple example of how to establish a connection between two different machines using RMI that would be awesome.  I don't need to see how its done for localhost, I've seen like million of those.

Thanks

Comment: Thee won't be any difference except, your RMI Server will be deployed on remote host and change client code URL from  localhost to remote host IP (or) machine name.,

Comment: For starters try replacing `localhost` with the ip address of the other machine.

Comment: That's what I don't get how can I bind registry to on Server side to the Server's IP?

Comment: Just create a Registry on a specific port on server side


    registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(registryPort);

And get the right registry at the client


    registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host, port);

Comment: You were already doing it correctly at the server, nothing needs to change. @Evil_skunk Changing the server in any way is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to change the client.

Change its Naming.lookup() string, from "localhost" to the server's hostname or IP address. The server's Naming string in the bind() or rebind() call does not change from "localhost", because the server and its Registry are always on the same host.

If you are using Registry instead of Naming, again you only have to change the client's LocateRegistry.getRegistry() call.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume we are connecting two Systems , A(server) with IP address 192.168.1.2 and B (client) with IP address 192.168.1.3 .
You should start the registry on server,i.e., system A then the Server Program should bind the Object like

```
Naming.rebind("rmi://192.168.1.2/myObject",obj);
```

Then compile the Client Program on system B which has the lookup function as

```
myInterface objHandle = (myInterface)Naming.lookup("rmi://192.168.1.2/myObject");
```

The main catch is that the two systems have to be on the same network for communicating, you might have to create your own network.

Comment: A `Naming.bind()/rebind()/unbind()` call can and probably should always use "localhost" rather than the real hostname or IP address. The Registry has to be co-resident with the server anyway so there is nothing to be gained, and portability to another host to be lost. Only the client needs the real hostname or IP address, in the `Naming.list()/lookup()` calls.